# Cyborg RAT 3 mouse requires relog

Tags: 12.04, xorg, mouse

To begin, I want to make clear that this is different from the other Cyborg Rat questions. This question is after following the answers.First

Okay, so since Christmas when I got the Cyborg Rat 3 mouse, using it in Ubuntu is a pain.

Once I sign in, it works for a bit, until I open a window, then clicking does nothing. It still moves, with only the clicking non-functioning.

I followed a few guides which suggested editing Xorg with the new button map, which worked.

However, when I reboot, the same problem persists unless I log off and sign back in.

So my question is: what can I do to eliminate the need to sign out and back in for the mouse to work?

Comment: Known problem... I had it too. But sorry, don't remember how I've fixed it. Greate mouse btw.

Comment: @OrangeTux - Just to confirm: you don't need to relog to fix any mouse issues?

Comment: I bought exact the same mouse last year, same issues. Gave it to my twin brother as birthday present(he's a windows user). I hope you have a twin brother too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I've been using and it seems to work.  Its available at [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11789197&postcount=15)

Cheers

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I can finally confirm that this works. I appreciate this fix. Thanks!